# Why do I get a security alert AFTER installing 4.6.14?

Tags: security-advisory, 4.6.14

I just installed 4.6.14 on a test system, and still get the security alert popup message at the top right of the screen, and on the last line of the screen.  Is this an error?  I cleared caches (Civi & Drupal) but still get the message.  I know I can suppress them but I don't think they should be appearing at all.

Answer (score 8):

There is an open issue on this: [CRM-18156](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18156).

This logic is implemented in `CRM_Utils_Version:: checkBranchForNewVersion()` -

- [check as implemented in v4.6](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.6/CRM/Utils/VersionCheck.php#L222)
- [check as implemented in master / v4.7](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/01dceae72feff7032688cdcbe00db8a9bd823c83/CRM/Utils/VersionCheck.php#L246)

**Update: Now fixed, cause was identified as data in the pingback / version check feed on CiviCRM.org. See [JIRA issue CRM-18156](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18156) for details.**

Answer (score 2):

4.6 will alert you if there is a security release of a higher version number. This includes all 4.7 security releases.

Beginning with 4.7 Civi will check for security release only on their current fork.

Comment: That is right, but not sure this is the issue in this case. I think that 4.6.14 is not causing the 'there is a security release' pop up to stop loading.

Comment: I have gotten it in 4.6.14

Comment: Tommy - this is interesting to me as I thought 4.6 already did that current-branch only check. I see the format of the version check has changed also.